# Nginx: Redirect all www. and non-ssl traffic to non-www and https

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect

In Nginx, is it possible to redirect all www. and non-ssl traffic to their opposites in a single server block? If so, how? If not, whats the best way to deal with these rules?

Heres what I'm trying to achieve:

```
http://www.example.com   >  https://example.com
https://www.example.com  >  https://example.com
http://example.com       >  https://example.com
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The http to https part is achieved this way:

```
if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
```

The www to non-www part has been answered many times over:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www

Bonus: As it looks like you want "TLS everywhere", I strongly suggest you look into including this Strict-Transport-Security header:

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload';
```

This will help browsers, search engines etc. remember that you want visitors to always go to the https equivalent page, saving your server the redirects and hence the resources to get them where you want them.

As hinted, when you ask a question, do try to demonstrate you have made some attempts to get it working yourself.

Comment: hmmm... you should really add some information about that first line, because adding that can cause problems if there is no expectation about what it does. It "might" be good practice but it is beyond what is being asked in the question, and it isn't required to simply redirect to https

Comment: STS helps reduce unnecessary redirects which reduces system resources. Sure it's optional, but if you redirect all http to https as requested, you may as well do the world and your server a favor and set STS headers.

Comment: But the answer rather then a comment should explain the difference in what it does

Comment: I have reorganised the answer to focus on the explicit question instead. Thanks for your feedback.